# Automatic version in DATETIME format on every "git push" on Heroku or elsewhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, version-control

Every time I change my project (whether in PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Javascript) I need that before executing commands routine:

`git add.` `git commit -am "blablabla"` and `git push heroku master`

(or another provider instead of Heroku) I automatically add a version of the project based on the date and time in a project file (for example: layout.hbs or application.html.erb).

I can use also a macro in Sublime Text or something else in Terminal, just I do not know what to use.

I don't want to use a ENV_VAR because I want that date and time WRITTEN in the file.

I'd also like to hear from you if you have solved in other ways, even using environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use git ?

You can get the date of your last commit by running `git show -s --format=%ci`

If you want it to be displayed somewhere in your app, you could run the git commands on the server side :

```
# add this action in the controller of your choice, 
# then you can access those variables in your view
def version
  @version_datetime = `git show -s --format=%ci`
  @version_tag = `git describe --tags`
end
```

That's just an example, but it should hopefully help you to get started.

Comment: But with this I can't write text in file, e.g. application.html.erb. I want to write definitely. Not use vars. How to?

Comment: Sorry but could you explain *why* you want to do that ?

Comment: I want to write directly in my "application.html.erb" file. I don't want to use vars in any way. How to?

Comment: Can you please explain **why** you want to write the file and not use variables ? What are you trying to achieve

Comment: I don't want to use a var because I want my app as fast as possible!

Comment: This is highly negligible. There's no performance impact to be considered here.

Comment: Is not better if I write it in the file?

Comment: you should let `git` handle the versioning job. The controller was just an example if you had a specific endpoint where you wanted to show the version. If you want to display it everywhere it might be worth initialising a constant when rails starts up, ie. in a initialiser file (environment.rb)

Comment: for example `MyApplication::APP_VERSION =\`git describe --tags\``